# Maven multi project issue

Tags: maven

I am having some issues with my multi-project Maven project.

The problem is the following:
I have a project that organized in the following way:

```
root
 +-- pom.xml
 !
 +-- module1 
 !     +-- pom.xml
 +-- module2
       +-- pom.xml
```

Where `module2` depends on `module1`.

`Module1` is packaged as `war`, it also generates `jar` file that `module2` depends on.
Everything is fine whenever the changes are only in `module2` i.e. `module1.jar` is already in remote repo, however whenever there are changes in both modules during `mvn clean release:clean release:prepare release:perform` I get an error saying that `module1.jar` could not be found in remote repo.
So to fix that I have added `maven-install-plugin` to the `Module1`'s pom file like this:

```
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <file>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.jar</file>
                        <!-- <packaging>jar</packaging> -->
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>install</id>
                            <phase>compile</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>install</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
```

whenever i comment out `<packaging>jar</packaging>` it tries to install `Module1` jar file into local repo as `war` file (I am guessing that by default it would pick up packaging from the POM file). So i get something like this:

```
[INFO] [INFO] [jar:jar {execution: creation}]
[INFO] [INFO] Building jar: ${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.jar
[INFO] [INFO] [install:install {execution: install}]
[INFO] [INFO] Installing ${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.jar to <.m2_local_repo>/<proper_path>/${project.version}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.war
```

However if i un-comment `<packaging>jar</packaging>` it complains that i am attempting to set a read-only property.

So the question i have, how can i install `jar` file to my local repo during my build?

Updating the question w/ some parts of `module1` and `module2` pom files:

`module2` pom parts:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>...</groupId>
    <artifactId>...</artifactId>
    <version>1.01-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>module2</artifactId>
<version>1.08-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

...

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>...</groupId>
    <artifactId>module1</artifactId>
    <version>4.18-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

`module1` pom:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>...</groupId>
    <artifactId>...</artifactId>
    <version>1.01-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>module1</artifactId>
<version>4.18-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

i added install plugin to make sure that `module1.4.18.jar` will be installed locally so that `module2.0.18.war` will be able to use `module1.4.18.jar`

Comment: What is version of parent POM and submododules?

Comment: root's pom: 1.01-SNAPSHOT, module1: 4.18-SNAPSHOT, module2: 1.08-SNAPSHOT and dependency is set up this way:   `<dependency>
   <groupId>module1 grpid</groupId>
   <artifactId>module1 artifact id</artifactId>
   <version>4.18-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <scope>compile</scope>
  </dependency>`

Comment: Parent pom has `<modules>` definition? Is special reason for diffrent version in parent and modules?

Comment: When invoked `mvn install` artefact `Module1.jar` is installed in local repo?

Comment: I recommend you create another module just for the code of Module1 that goes into the jar, and make the `war` project used the jar as a dependency.

Comment: @MariuszS yes parent has modules: ` <modules>
  <module>module1</module>
  <module>module2</module>
 </modules>`

Comment: @MariuszS if i do mvn clean install it does the same thing as in case mvn clean release:xxxx it attempting to install jar to the local repo but as war

Comment: @WIll that is the notion i got from reading different posts, however it would work fine if i can use `<packaging>jar</packaging>`for install plugin>configuration. I guess a real question why give it as an option if you can not override it, unless i am missing something

Comment: Why are you invoking `mvn clean release:clean release:prepare release:perform` - this is for install?

Answer (score 0):

I think your project has wrong configuration (not in maven way). Proper configuration looks like this

```
* parent (root)
    * module1 (war1)
    * module2 (war2)
    * jar (shared code from war2)
```

Move your code from war to separate module and add this module as depdency to both war modules.

Comment: true, but it will attempt to resolve them from the remote repository, and in my case `module1.jar` is not there, yet

Comment: No, should not. Invoking `mvn clean install` from parent POM properly installing all submodules in local repo?

Comment: As I answered to your question above it attempts to install jar into local repo as war

Comment: Im confused, you are installing or releasing this project?

Answer (score 0):

eventually i went with `<goal>install-file</goal>` instead of `<goal>install</goal>`
this way i was able to specify proper packaging (it turns out that `packaging` on `install` goal is read only, but you can override it for `install-file`)

so this is what i end up with:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>install</id>
                <phase>compile</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>install-file</goal>
                </goals>
            <configuration>
                <file>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.jar</file>
                <packaging>jar</packaging>
            </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

@MariuszS and @WIll- thank you for your insight on this matter

Comment: Instead of using `maven-install-plugin` you can also use [build-helper:attach-artifact](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/attach-artifact-mojo.html), but generally this is bad idea to configure project in this way.